# CSS Triangle under rectangle

Tags: html, css

[image]

This is what i want to get. At the moment i have only a rectangle with text inside. Have no idea how to create this rectangle under it.

Code:

```
.txt_First {
    font-size:0.8em;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
.com_box {
    width:60px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
    color:white;
    float:left;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
    margin-right:8px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top:1px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="com_box">71</div>
      <div class="txt_First">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
      </div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wrm4y8k6/

Comment: Try searching here for "CSS Triangles" and go from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```css
.txt_First {
    font-size:0.8em;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
.com_box {
    width:60px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
    color:white;
    float:left;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
    margin-right:8px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top:1px;
    position: relative;
}
.com_box:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 10px 0 0;
    border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
 }
```

```html
<div class="com_box">71</div>
<div class="txt_First">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000000;
}
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 20px 0 0;
  border-color: #000000 transparent transparent transparent;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this

```
.com_box::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid black;
  clear: both;
}
```

And put `.com_box` to `position:relative`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qchL9v36/)

Answer (score 1):

See example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrm4y8k6/6/)

HTML:

```
<div id="triangle-down"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#triangle-down {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 margin-left:20px;
 border-left: 0px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 border-top: 15px solid black;
}
```